# How to write query in MongoDB to search data between two dates on behalf of custom id in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongodb-query, nodes

My collection is below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d88953e7a20304f3c76f264"),
    "purchaseId" : "5d88953e7a20304f3c76f263",
    "partId" : "5d2584b5d24e8b3f0885737b",
    "SellPrice" : "1885",
    "TotalAmnt" : "2667.24",
    "Tax" : "28",
    "Discount" : "8708",
    "Quantity" : "2",
    "Price" : "1985",
    "Per" : "PCS",
    "DiscountAmnt" : "32.815",
    "Sgst" : "373.41",
    "Cgst" : "373.41",
    "Igst" : "746.83",
    "TotalAmntData" : "3414.06",
    "salecostprice" : "1707",
    "finalqtydata" : "4",
    "part" : "542746990101",
    "purchaseStatus" : "0",
    "datetime" : "2019-09-23",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I try this query

```
db.purchaseitems.find({ "part" : "542746990101":{ $gte: "datetime" : "2019-09-23", $lte: "datetime" : "2019-09-23")}});
```

Comment: what do you mean by the phrase 'on behalf of Custom id'?

Comment: Values in field `datetime` are a string, not an ISODate.  Do you have the option of changing the schema?

Comment: I need those data whose customer id is this ex - 542746990101 and data had stored between start date 15-10-2019 and 18-10-2019 dates.

Comment: I don't see Customer Id in the example document.  Should it be there?

Comment: @barrypicker sorry for that its name is  "part" : "542746990101". part is available in my collection.

Comment: @barrypicker yes its available in my collection.

Comment: Hi @mayank Hardiya - Just a heads-up.  If you insist on storing date data as a string you must then consider the format of the string and rely on string greater than/less than operators instead of datetime operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query assuming you insist on using string to hold date values...

```
db.purchaseitems.find({ 
  $and:
    [
      { "partId" : "5d2584b5d24e8b3f0885737b" },
      { "datetime": { "$gte": "2019-09-23" } },
      { "datetime": { "$lte": "2019-09-23" } }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use following line

```
const lastUpdateDateCond = { datetime: { $gt: new Date('2019-09-23) }
```

Please use new keyword in date filter

Comment: all kinds of interesting an unpredictable things can happen when the date values are stored as a string.  The assumption is that the function Date() will produce a string in a format of YYYY-MM-DD, but if the locale on the host has defined a different format the results may not be as expected.  Consider if the function Date() returned date data in the format MM-DD-YYYY.  Now a date of February 1, 2018 represented as 2018-02-01 will show as occurring after February 1, 2019 when the date is represented as 02-01-2019 (via string comparison).

Comment: @barrypicker thanks for sharing valuable information.

Comment: I need those data whose customer id is this ex - 542746990101 and data had stored between start date 15-10-2019 and 18-10-2019 dates.